# Can i ensure vector elements are always in memory

Tags: c++, c++98

I am working on a heavy weight application where the application is the only application runing on the system. On a recent performance run it was found that we were taking a lot of time in derefereing a very large vector  of pointers  . I found that we have large swapin/out as well giving me an indication that may be the vector element memory was released from ram. Can I ensure that my elements pointed to by pointers which are contained in my vector  never go out of ram . Gcc 4.8 and  Not c++11 . Red hat v6.5 . We cant use c++ 11 as per management dicission .

Comment: Do you mean GCC 4.8 or C++ 4.8 (which doesn't exist)?

Comment: The vector elements are not "released from ram"; they are *swapped out of RAM* but still inside the (virtual) memory. Besides, [GCC 4.8 supports C++11](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html).

Comment: Updated in question too that we cant move to c++11 as  per policy   . So is there a way to avoid this swap?

Comment: (a) Redesign the application so it doesn't need so much memory. (b) Buy more memory. If you manage to lock the data in RAM, you may very well find another block of memory gets paged in and out instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can't solve this problem using any C++ language features. What you need is support from the operation system.

Luckily Linux offers an API that lets you mark memory pages that should not get swapped out. You'll find these in mman.h: [mlock man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html)

So if you want your vector to always be present in RAM you should:

- Allocate a large enough chunk of memory.
- Mark as unswappable using mlock
- Write a custom allocator for your vector that takes memory from your unswappable memory block instead from the heap.

Keep in mind: The OS will not swap out memory for no reason. If part of your vector reside on the harddisk, something else you've accessed recently was more important. If you start experimenting with unswappable memory be ready for some performance surprises. The OS already tries to do it's best.